# How to display custom data into Header file of Tcpdf?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a class that extend to class `TCPDF` for generating report. Inside this class i made a function that is task to do the report generation when called by certain button from my page, I am now wondering how can i add a custom text on the header of my report so far this is what i have done:

```php
class Pdf extends TCPDF{

    private $data;

    public function setData($fields){
        $this->data = $fields;
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function Header()
    {
        $this->SetFont('times', 'B', 8);
        $html = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
         <tr>
          <td style="height: 10px; font-family: Times New Roman"> Serial number: '.$this->data['flag'].'</td>
         </tr>
        </table>';

        $this->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    }

    function generateReport()
    {
        $pdf = new Pdf('P','mm','A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $pdf->SetMargins(5, 30, 5, true);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('freeserif', 'B', 8);
        ...
    }
}
```

and on my page this is how i call my class:

```
...
$report = new Pdf();
$report->setData($fields);
$report->generateReport();
...
```

where my `$fields` is of type array that holds all information feed to my class.

**My problem now is *no data is displayed (empty) using my variable* on my Header** as for the body content of the report all information is shown properly.

Comment: Can you tell us the library you are using to generate the report.

Comment: I download a library from github created by sir @nicolaasuni